# Converting Map<K, V> to Map<V,List<K>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have map as below

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("aa", "20");
values.put("bb", "30");
values.put("cc", "20");
values.put("dd", "45");
values.put("ee", "35");
values.put("ff", "35");
values.put("gg", "20");
```

I want to create new map in the format  `Map<String,List<String>>`  , sample output will be as

```
"20" -> ["aa","cc","gg"]
"30" -> ["bb"]
"35" -> ["ee","ff"]     
"45" -> ["dd"]
```

I am able to do by iterating through entity

```
Map<String, List<String>> output = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet()) {
        if(output.containsKey(entry.getValue())){
            output.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());

        }else{
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(entry.getKey());
            output.put(entry.getValue(),list);
          }
    }
```

Can this be done better using streams?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`groupingBy` can be used to group the keys by the values. If used without a `mapping` `Collector`, it will transform a `Stream` of map entries (`Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>>`) to a `Map<String,List<Map.Entry<String,String>>`, which is close to what you want, but not quite.

In order for the value of the output `Map` to be a `List` of the original keys, you have to chain a `mapping` `Collector` to the `groupingBy` `Collector`.

```
Map<String,List<String>> output =
    values.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                         Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                            Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println (output);
```

Output :

```
{45=[dd], 35=[ee, ff], 30=[bb], 20=[aa, cc, gg]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Java 8, you can also do better without using streams using [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). This way, it is more concise than the old version with `Map.Entry<String, String>`, `entry.getValue()`, `entry.getKey()` etc.

So you don't have to compare the old Java-7 iteration to that Java-8 stream solution, but to this one.

```
values.forEach( (key,value)->
    groupBy.computeIfAbsent(value, x->new ArrayList<>())
           .add(key)
);
```